# Get Form Authentication Details SAPUI5

Tags: java, sapui5

I have created my own test application on the trial hana platform. It is using the FORM authentication and I was wondering if it is possible to access the username in the frontend home controller for a data call based on the logged in user?

Thank you

Comment: What is SAP context? No SAP systems as backend. I will use the username to do an oData call to success factors to get all the users information

Comment: I was asking because in SAP there is the SICF service `/sap/bc/ui2/start_up` that will give you lots of information about the logged in user. (Fullname, Mail, Language, Timezone, etc...)

Comment: Really, never seen/ heard of the SICF service? How would I implement that? Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted out the issue, in the end I needed to create a servlet that did a httpRequest to get the RemoteUser which is the current logged on user for success factors and parse it back to frontend.